# Registered and unregistered facebook friends in an app

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app. I want to invite my  facebook friends to app. To do that I want friends who are registered or unregistered with the app. I want only fb name and fb id of the friends. I have users table in which I am saving the fb id and name of the users. So I am getting my friends via the below code:

```
    var request = require('request');
    var urls="https://graph.facebook.com/" + fbId + "/friends?access_token=" +fbAccessToken;
    request(urls, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var output = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(output['data']);     //getting fb friends
           }
           });
```

Want two array like {"registered_fb_friends":[{"name":abc,fb_id:100003323882},{"name":xyz,fb_id:100003376765}],"unregistered_fb_friends":[{"name":jkl,fb_id:1000076563882},{"name":asd,fb_id:1000033456675}]}
Please suggest code for achieving this.

Comment: See `installed` field of the [user object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).